# Mining Rig with old motherboard with RX470 + Intel Core 2 Duo

Tags: mining, ether, rig

So I am thinking of buying an Asus Radeon RX 470 ROG Strix 4GB GPU to use on an old motherboard I had lying around with 1 x PCIE 16, 2 x PCIE 1 and 1 x PCI slot.

[image: Intel IPIEL-RN2 Motherboard]

The motherboard also has an Intel Core 2 Duo E7500 in it that I plan to use as well as 2 x 2GB RAM sticks and 2 x 1GB RAM sticks.

[image: 1GB and 2GB RAM sticks]

I have a few questions about this:
1. Will the old components slow down the GPU's ability to mine?
2. Does RAM speed matter for a mining rig?
3. Is it better to just use the 2 x 2GB RAM sticks? I have heard some things about one-sided RAM sticks not working well and the 1GB sticks are one-sided.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it and here's what I found out:

1. Unfortunately the motherboard wouldn't work with the GPU and the powersupply that came with it was proprietary (Dell) and couldn't be used with any other motherboard. I did buy another old motherboard for cheap and it worked fine. So no, as long as the components don't slow down the graphics card then you will have no problems.
2. The speed from the RAM sticks doesn't matter from what I have found. I believe only the graphics card RAM is used for mining. That is why overclocking the GPU RAM has such an effect on hashrate.
3. No idea. But it won't effect mining.